# How to find the ipaddress of a server which is used for accepting a client in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, ipv6

I have to find the ipaddress of a machine in which my server program is running. Server is listening to all addresses(::0 - ipv6). Now I need to find the ip in which is accepting a client connection. I tried with getsockname(), but it is not working. It gives me an ip 0.0.0.0 even if i am using socket descriptor which accept() returns.

Code snippet:

```
addr_len = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
res = getsockname (client, (struct sockaddr *)&addr,(socklen_t*) &addr_len);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(addr.sin_addr), ip_str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
IPaddr = ip_str;
```

But if i replace ipv6 address(::0) with ipv4 counterpart(0.0.0.0), This code is working. Can anyone guide me to make this generic and work with both versions of ip address?

Comment: I think you should use AF_INET6 then.

Comment: I have already tried with AF_INET6, but it didnt work.